# Imbed matplotlib figure into iPython HTML

Tags: html, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I want to dynamically write and display HTML with a code cell in Jupyter Notebook.  The objective is to generate the HTML to display table, div, img tags in some way I choose.  I want to capture img data and place it where I want in this auto generated HTML.

So far I've figured out that I can do the following:

```
from IPython.core.display import HTML

HTML("<h1>Hello</h1>")
```

and get:

## Hello

That's great.  However, I want to be able to do this:

```
HTML("<h1>Hello</h1><hr/><img src='somestring'/>")
```

and get something similar to a **Hello** with a horizontal line and an image below it, where the image is the same one as below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(314)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 2), columns=['x', 'y'])

df.plot.scatter(0, 1)
```

[image]

The result should look like this:

[image]

#### Question

What do I replace `'something'` with in order to implement this?  And more to the point, how do I get it via python?

I would have imagined there was an attribute on a figure object that would hold an serialized version of the image but I can't find it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some digging around.  Credit to Dmitry B. for pointing me in the right direction.

#### Solution

```
from IPython.core.display import HTML
import binascii
from StringIO import StringIO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# open IO object
sio = StringIO()

# generate random DataFrame
np.random.seed(314)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 2), columns=['x', 'y'])

# initialize figure and axis
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

# plot DataFrame
ax.scatter(df.iloc[:, 0], df.iloc[:, 1]);

# print raw canvas data to IO object
fig.canvas.print_png(sio)

# convert raw binary data to base64
# I use this to embed in an img tag
img_data = binascii.b2a_base64(sio.getvalue())

# keep img tag outter html in its own variable
img_html = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,{}&#10;">'.format(img_data)

HTML("<h1>Hello</h1><hr/>"+img_html)
```

I end up with:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The answer by piRSquared no longer works with Python 3.  I had to change it to:

```py
from IPython.core.display import HTML
import binascii
from io import BytesIO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# open IO object
bio = BytesIO()

# generate random DataFrame
np.random.seed(314)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 2), columns=['x', 'y'])

# initialize figure and axis
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1);

# plot DataFrame
ax.scatter(df.iloc[:, 0], df.iloc[:, 1]);

# print raw canvas data to IO object
fig.canvas.print_png(bio)
plt.close(fig)

# convert raw binary data to base64
# I use this to embed in an img tag
img_data = binascii.b2a_base64(bio.getvalue()).decode()

# keep img tag outter html in its own variable
img_html = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,{}&#10;">'.format(img_data)

HTML("<h1>Hello</h1><hr/>"+img_html)
```

Specifically, I import from io, not StringIO, and I use BytesIO rather than StringIO. I needed to decode the bytes into a string for inserting into the HTML.  I also added the required imports of numpy and pandas for the example plot to work, and added plt.close(fig) so that you don't end up with two figures in the output.

Answer (score 2):

```
from IPython.core.display import Image
import io

s = io.BytesIO()

# make your figure here

plt.savefig(s, format='png', bbox_inches="tight")
plt.close()

Image(s.getvalue())
```

Answer (score 1):

Let say you have base64 encoded image data:

```
img_data = 

"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"
```

then in have it rendered inside of an iPython cell you simply do:

```
from IPython.core.display import Image
Image(data=img_data)
```

Comment: but how do I get that `img_data`?  I can see it by inspecting the element.  But how do I get it via python?

Comment: Ok, I'm confused at what the problem is.  Are you trying to show in iPython the results of `df.plot.scatter(0, 1)` or some other image?  I understood it as that you have some other image you want to show like `df.plot.scatter(0, 1)`

Comment: Your answer hard codes img_data. I want to access some property or method to retrieve img_data. Get me that and this is the answer.

Comment: retrieve it from where?!

Comment: Where did you get the string to you asigned to `img_data`.  I'm guessing you got it from inspecting the output cell's html and copying the string.  I can't inspect and copy every time I want to do this.  I need to get that string some other way.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to build on what was answered by others (piRSquared) because it didn't work for me with Jupyter and Python 3. I wrote the following function, which will take any plot function I define and call it, and capture the outputs without displaying them in Jupyter. I personally use this in to build custom HTML machine learning reports based on many model iterations I execute using Livy and Spark.

```py
from IPython.core.display import HTML
import binascii
from io import BytesIO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import base64

def capturePlotHTML(plotFunction): 
    # open IO object
    sio3 = BytesIO() 
    plotFunction()
    plt.savefig(sio3)
    sio3.seek(0)
    data_uri = base64.b64encode(sio3.read()).decode('ascii')
    html_out = '<html><head></head><body>'
    html_out += '<img src="data:image/png;base64,{0}" align="left">'.format(data_uri)
    html_out += '</body></html>'
    #prevents plot from showing in output
    plt.close()
    return (HTML(html_out))


# Plot Wrappers

# Advanced Wrapper for more complex visualizations (seaborn, etc)
class plotRegline:
    def __init__(self):
    #// could also pass in name as arg like this #def __init__(self, name):
        reg_line_prepped_pdf = pandas_input_pdf
        sns.lmplot(x='predicted',y='actual',data=reg_line_prepped_pdf,fit_reg=True, height=3, aspect=2).fig.suptitle("Regression Line")

# Basic Wrapper for simple matplotlib visualizations
def plotTsPred():
        ts_plot_prepped_pdf = pandas_input_pdf
        ts_plot_prepped_pdf.index = pd.to_datetime(ts_plot_prepped_pdf.DAYDATECOLUMN)
        ts_plot_prepped_pdf = ts_plot_prepped_pdf.drop(columns=["DAYDATECOLUMN"])
        ts_plot_prepped_pdf.plot(title="Predicted Vs Actual -- Timeseries Plot -- Days", figsize=(25,6))

#building the plots and capturing the outputs 
regline_html = capturePlotHTML(plotRegline)
ts_plot_day_html = capturePlotHTML(plotTsPred)

# could be any list number of html objects
html_plots =  [regline_html, ts_plot_day_html]
combined_html_plots = display_html(*html_plots)
# the following can be run in this code block or another display the results 
combined_html_plotes
```

Comment: I’ll check this out more thoroughly when I get back in front of a terminal. Thx for the answer.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to show the results of DataFrame.plot in an iPython cell, try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline


np.random.seed(314)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 2), columns=['x', 'y'])

df.plot.scatter(0, 1)
```