# `%%capture` jupyter notebook or colab doesn't work for storing cell output that display image or table pandas

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, stdout

I have read docs about `%%capture cap`. It only work for text representation. I expect it stored everything what has been displayed into cell output; image, table, even html element.

And then I can load it into another cell with same identical output:

## CELL_A

```
%%capture cap

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Data
x = [1, 2]
y = [3, 4]

# Create a simple plot
plt.plot(x, y)

# Add labels to the axes
plt.xlabel('X-axis')
plt.ylabel('Y-axis')

# Add a title to the plot
plt.title('Simple Plot Example')

# Show the plot
plt.show()

# Save the captured output to a text file
with open('stdout.txt', 'w') as file:
  file.write(cap.stdout)
```

## CELL_B

```
#@title Reloading CELL_A output

with open('stdout.txt', 'r') as file:
  cell_a_out = file.read()

display(cell_a_out)
```

It should be display matplotlib image. I know matplotlib provide save figure method to save the image. But I expect to save everything that has been displayed in the cell output, not only image. Therefore if the cell returning output table of pandas and matplotlib image it can be stored in the single file.

Comment: You are misinformed about what you are dealing with given your post title **and last paragraph**. Your example code is not making an image. You are making a plot figure or object that Jupyter displays. Alternatively, **although you inexplicably dismiss it**, you can save an image of a plot, using `plt.savefig()`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9890599/8508004). And then you answer your own question with a way that is not going to be supported in current JupyterLab and Jupyter Notebook 7+. Please add to your particular answer that is for Google Colab.

Comment: If given our comment of 'Therefore if the cell returning output table of pandas and matplotlib image it can be stored in the single file.' you are doing this just to have the matplotlib plot be stored in the same Jupyter `.ipynb` file you are going out of your way for no reason. Example for plots: see [the nbviewer rendering here](https://nbviewer.org/github/binder-examples/requirements/blob/main/index.ipynb) (and the actual GitHub file preview [here](https://github.com/binder-examples/requirements/blob/main/index.ipynb)). Seaborn is built on matplotlib and is the example I had...

Comment: <continued>  handiest. I could probably dig up more Matplotlib plots. And even ones saved as image files in `.png` form and then displayed using the convenient established way of something like `from IPython.display import Image` on one line of a cell followed by `Image("my_plot_image.png")` on the next line.  Oh wait, I think you are trying to make a report!! Like save a file of a cell output that has a dataframe and matplotlib object. Got it now. **Nevermind the first part of my last comment.** So you can save the matplotlib plot as an image file using what I just said and then also ...

Comment: <continued> save the dataframe as image, using [dataframe_image](https://github.com/dexplo/dataframe_image), as a I describe [here in an update to my own pipeline to address that](https://github.com/fomightez/dataframe2img#update). Then you can use reportlab or pillow to combine the files and output as pdf or whatever form you prefer, all using Python in a typical Jupyter notebook. Additionally, despite your title, you should be able to use capture to get a redisplay a plot, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/how-to-display-plots-only-after-plt-show-in-jup-notebook/2863/2?u=fomightez).

Comment: <continued> Again though that is the plot object and not an image. You can though redisplay plots usually much easier if you assign them, for examples, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70707556/8508004), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71187975/8508004), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60269307/8508004), or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76707536/8508004).

Comment: By the way, you cannot expect `cap.stdout` to work as you show in CELL_A because as takluyver says "%%capture won't define the variable until after the code inside it has run, so it's not meant to be used in the cell it's capturing.", see source of that quote [here](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4040#issuecomment-436728362).

Answer (score 0):

Just get element by id `output-area` and `innerHTML` in cell A and then simply display HTML string

## CELL A

```
from google.colab import output
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Data
x = [1, 2]
y = [3, 4]

# Create a simple plot
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlabel('X-axis')
plt.ylabel('Y-axis')
plt.title('Simple Plot Example')
plt.show() # This will display image

# Execute JavaScript code and get `output-area`
output_from_cell_a = output.eval_js('document.getElementById("output-area").innerHTML;')
print(output_from_cell_a) # this will return HTML string
print(type(output_from_cell_a)) # this will return `str`
```

## CELL B

```
from IPython.display import HTML, display

# Redisplay output from cell A
display(HTML(output_from_cell_a))
```

As you can guess, you can store the string of html variable `output_from_cell_a` into file with `open(output_from_cell_a.html)` and can be loaded any time.

Hence you can store identical output of cell A to the file and load it with HTML.

Comment: Please see my comments below the original post by the same person as there are much more direct and well-supported routes to accomplish this in Jupyter in combination with Python without necessarily resorting to javascript and HTML manipulations that may not work well with modern Jupyter (I have yet to test but this seems to be for Google Colab given `from google.colab import output`), but sometimes you just want to get to making a report so maybe this route is also useful at times.

Answer (score 0):

As I discussed in my comments your post reflects several key misunderstandings.

- What is being displayed by matplotlib with your example plotting code in your OP (your CELL_A). (It isn't an image!)
- That you can use captured output in the same cell you call it (see your CELL_A in your OP). [Here](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4040#issuecomment-436728362) takluyver puts it succinctly as, "`%%capture` won't define the variable until after the code inside it has run, so it's not meant to be used in the cell it's capturing."

Here is how you can do what you say in the title and more using `%%capture`.

First cell (your CELL_A but removing the ill-informed idea of using the captured object before cell completely run):

### CELL 1

```py
%%capture cap

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Data
x = [1, 2]
y = [3, 4]

# Create a simple plot
plt.plot(x, y)

# Add labels to the axes
plt.xlabel('X-axis')
plt.ylabel('Y-axis')

# Add a title to the plot
plt.title('Simple Plot Example')

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

(By the way, `plt.show()` is generally no longer needed because when using the Python kernel, modern Jupyter sees a matplotlib plot object being made and displays it whether `plt.show()` is there or not. Though here because you want to use `%%capture` it's good to use because otherwise you may get `cap` including the last expression evaluated as part of the `cap` output, for example the plot title object.)

Note the object made by the code in the previous cell if you remove the `%%capture` line isn't an image at this point. It would be a matplotlib plot object that Jupyter would handle displaying.

Reshowing the captured output based on [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/how-to-display-plots-only-after-plt-show-in-jup-notebook/2863/2?u=fomightez) in Cell #2:

### CELL 2

```py
#Reloading CELL 1 output
cap.show()
```

### Alternative CELL 2 option

```py
from IPython.display import display
display(cap.outputs[0])
```

Okay, what if you did want to make the object generated in cell #1 an image and display it in the notebook?
First, we'll assign the plot object to a handle that we can call again make an it into an image and in the second step display that image in the notebook.

### ALTERNATIVE CELL 1

```py
%%capture cap

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Data
x = [1, 2]
y = [3, 4]

# Create a simple plot
my_plot = plt.plot(x, y)

# Add labels to the axes
plt.xlabel('X-axis')
plt.ylabel('Y-axis')

# Add a title to the plot
plt.title('Simple Plot Example')

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

Note the only difference is I assigned a handle to the plot object for ease in recalling subsequently.

Next based on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70707556/8508004) we can show the plot in another cell. (The `%%capture cap` swallowed the output and so it wasn't shown as output from the first cell already.)

### ALTERNATIVE CELL 2

```py
my_plot[0].figure
```

Let's save that matplotlib object as an image file:

### ALTERNATIVE CELL 3

```py
# make an image file of the matplotlib object
my_plot[0].figure.savefig("my_plot_as_image.png")
```

### ALTERNATIVE CELL 4

```py
#display the image of the plot made
from IPython.display import Image
Image("my_plot_as_image.png")
```

Note that when the Jupyter `.ipynb` file gets saved it will encode the image file within the saved `.ipynb` as Base64 code. (You can even recover as a file that embedded image from within the code later if you need to, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/how-to-convert-mime-png-back-to-a-regular-image/9929/2?u=fomightez).)

If you wanted to combine it with a dataframe there are number of options, see 'related' below for some ideas, as well as [dataframe_image](https://github.com/dexplo/dataframe_image) if you wanted to do it with an image if the plot is stored as an image, too.
Then, you could use `jupyter nbconvert` commands to save HTML, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47773056/8508004). And extract the HTML you wanted for an alternative option to what you describe for your answer to get HTML of your items.

I like PDFs for reports and so I't probably combine images of the plot and dataframe into PDF using ReportLab or Pillow.

Finally...
Your title and original post also seems to reflect an XY problem. You seem to at the end of your post are trying to do this to make a file that is just the plot and dataframe. In the future research and ask about the goal you have in mind and not how you think you might be able to accomplish it. See [why not to do that here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Related:

- [answers to 'Combining Jupyter rich display and matplotlib charts'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37396886/8508004)