# How to save what jupyter's display() shows?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Jupyter's display function is great for displaying a variety of objects (e.g. a dataframe). It seems that for many (most?) cases internally a bitmap, SVG, or HTML asset is created? Is there a way to generically save to file what `display()` shows?

I only see examples  to do *similar* via 3rd party APIs (e.g. for dataframes specifically, how to uses pandas APIs and [third party APIs](https://ljmartin.github.io/sideprojects/df_to_svg.html) to save a png or svg which doesn't have the same rendering at the output shown by Jupyter):

```
for x, name in things:
  display(makey(x), saveAs=f"{name}.svg")
```

or

```
for x, name in things:
  display(makey(x))
  saveAsJupyterShowsIt(makey(x), saveAs=f"{name}.svg")
```

This would be a more convenient and more consistent in a WYISWG sense than dropping down to lower APIs.

Comment: Because those who end up here may be looking at how to use Python to catch the rich output Jupyter makes, I wanted to point out that the capture ability of IPython can be imported into Python and used to capture RichOutput. [At my answer in the thread 'How do I construct a python function where the input in python code and output is ipython rich output (in HTML)?'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74694087/8508004), I have the section 'UPDATE IN RESPONSE TO FIRST COMMENT:' where I talk about using IPython as an import in Python to capture RichOutput, ...

Comment: <continued> with that approach further [fleshed out in a demo](https://nbviewer.org/gist/fomightez/405e049fa082cca9b7a0ef0bee904b4f) that goes into some acrobatics you can do utilizing methods and functions from IPython in Jupyter.

Comment: You may also wish to see [this answer 'Is there a way to save the output of a cell?'](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/is-there-a-way-to-save-the-output-of-a-cell/2489/12?u=fomightez) and maybe the rest of the thread for other ideas/options.

Answer (score 0):

In a linux machine, what I do is tag the cells whose output I want to ignore and then use:

`jupyter nbconvert notebookName.ipynb --to html --TagRemovePreprocessor.enabled=True --TagRemovePreprocessor.remove_cell_tags="['tag1', 'tag2']" --no-input`

This will export your notebook to .html, without the input code but only cells you selected (which can be those displayed by the display function).

Then the .html be graciously seen on any browser.